react-timeseries-charts not plotting on safari only - error parsing d=1234NaN,
I have a website that is using the reactjs react-timeseries-charts component for displaying graphs.
For some reason, when using any other browser besides safari, it works as intended with no errors.   When i try and open with Safari, the bar charts and line graphs come up blank and through an error in react-dom.development.js saying "unable to parse: d=12345NaN, 45678NaN".  I don't quite understand how to troubleshoot errors logged in react-dom.development.js.  Clearly the "NaNs" are the problem, but I dont know where they are coming from.  When I examine the DOM elements, on Safari, the  tag has x="NaN" that is not present in chrome, so the actual width of the bars is not being properly set.  The X-axis is also not rendering.
[Chrome][1]
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/MB3Q6NAp.png
Here is the relevant snippet from render():
render(){
return(<div className="chart" id="chart" onTouchMove={this.handleTouchMove} onTouchStart={this.handleTouchStart} onTouchEnd={this.handleTouchEnd}>
                            <ChartContainer
                                timeRange={this.state.timerange}
                                width={this.state.width}
                                utc={true}
                                format={this.formatTime}
                                onBackgroundClick={() => this.setState({ selection: null })}
                                onTimeRangeChanged={this.handleTimeRangeChange}
                                timeAxisAngledLabels={false}
                                timeAxisTickCount={this.state.tickCount}
                                enablePanZoom={true}
                                minDuration={this.state.minDuration}
                                minTime={this.state.window_min}
                                maxTime={this.state.window_max}
                                paddingTop={this.state.paddingTop}
                                paddingLeft={this.state.paddingLeft}
                                paddingBottom={this.state.paddingBottom}
                                paddingRight={this.state.paddingRight}
                                timeAxisStyle={{
                                    ticks: {
                                        stroke: "#000000", 
                                        opacity: 1
                                    }, 
                                    values: {
                                        fill: "#000000", 
                                        "font-size": "1.75vw",
                                    }, 
                                    axis: {
                                        stroke: "#000000"
                                    }
                                }}
                            >
                            <ChartRow height={this.state.height}>
                                <YAxis
                                        id="axis"
                                        label=""
                                        min={0}
                                        max={this.state.y_max > this.state.rate ? this.state.y_max : (this.state.rate*1.1)}
                                        width="80" //changed
                                        type="linear"
                                        labelOffset={2}
                                        style={{
                                            label: {
                                                fill:"#000000"
                                            }, 
                                            values: {
                                                fill: "#000000",
                                                "font-size": "1.75vw",
                                            }, 
                                            ticks: {
                                                opacity: 1,
                                                stroke:"#000000"
                                            },
                                            axis: {
                                                stroke: "#000000"
                                            }
                                        }}
                                        format={function (n){ return Number(n).toFixed(1)}}
                                />
                                <Charts>
                                    <BarChart
                                        axis="axis"
                                        style={column_style}
                                        spacing={this.state.spacing}
                                        columns={this.state.active_columns}
                                        offset={3}
                                        series={this.state.Series}
                                        infoTimeFormat={(index) =>
                                                (<tspan style={{ fill: "black", fontSize: "0.8rem", fontWeight: "bold" }}>Hour: {moment(index.begin()).utc().format("HHmm")}</tspan>)} //Info box time display and format
                                        info={infoValues} //Info box on hover
                                        infoWidth={130}
                                        infoHeight={40}
                                        infoStyle={{ 
                                            label: {
                                                fill: "#000000",
                                                "font-size": "0.8rem",
                                            },
                                            values: {
                                                fill: "#000000"
                                            }, 
                                            box: { 
                                                stroke: "#000000", 
                                                opacity: 0.4,
                                            }
                                        }}
                                        infoOffsetY={150} //Info box stem height
                                        stemStyle={{
                                            stroke: "#000000", 
                                            cursor: "crosshair"
                                        }}
                                        markerStyle={{ fill: "#000000" }}
                                        highlighted={ this.state.highlight }
                                        onHighlightChange={highlight => this.setState({ highlight })}
                                    />


                                </Charts>
                            </ChartRow>
                        </ChartContainer>
                       </div>);
    }


Here is the relevant function for setting the timeseries:
        let points = [];
        let one = 0, two = 0, three = 0, four = 0;
        for(let i in data){
             if(some condition){
               one++;
             }else if (some other condition){
               two++;
             }else if (some other condition){
               three++;
             }else{
               four++;
             }
        }

                points.push({
                    "index": time,
                    "one": one,
                    "two": two,
                    "three": three,
                    "four": four
                });
        for (let i in data) {
            const d = new Date(data[i].index);
            const index = Index.getIndexString(interval, d);
            points.push([index, data[i].one, data[i].two, data[i].three, data[i].four]);
                if (points.length > 0) {
                const series = new TimeSeries({
                    name: "BarChart",
                    columns: ["index", "one", "two", "three", "four"],
                    points: points
            });

I made some changes to mask the nature of the code and what it is for, so there may be some typos with regards to that.
I do know that react-timeseries-charts is throwing errors for NaN height and y values when the data points contains a value of 0 for one of the four values (one, two, three, four), but it still renders in chrome.
Any help would be appreciated.

Closing this.  the documentation says react-timeseries-charts does not support safari.
Ended up migrating to ChartJS instead.
